# follow path constraint lost

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I have created an object following a curve. That works fine. To messure the length
of the curve using the add-on measurelt I converted the curve to a mesh. Then I converted
the mesh back into a curve. Now the object does not follow the curve any more.
Removing the follow path constraint and add it again did not help.
Can you help me understanding what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

The question, what is the result of first converting  a Bezier curve to a mesh and then back to a curve is still interesting. But I found a way to solve my original problem. I think it is not a work-around but the proper way of doing it. I needed to extend a Bezier curve by a new curve of fixed precomputed length. This is what I do: I generate an auxiliary  polygon of the desired length exactly in the place where I need the extended curve with the help of "measurelt".  Then I extend the Bezier curve following the polygon. Then I delete the auxiliary polygon.